# tangent circles radical axis proof

Tags: geometry, circles

Two Circles with centers $O_1$ and $O_2$ are tangent exterior at point T. Let points A and B be on the common tangent line through T such that T is between A and B. The tangent lines from A and B to circle $O_1$ meet at point M and the tangent line from A and B to circle $O_2$ meet at point N.

Prove that AM+BN=AN+BM

I know that ATB is the radical axis of the two circles. I am assuming the proof is about power of the point of points M, N, A, and B. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Isn't AN = BN and AM = BM?

Comment: @fleablood Possibly. Why would they be equal?

Comment: @fleablood I thought so at first glance, but I think that requires $TB=AT$. All that's given is $T$ is between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If TA does not equal TA than the tangent lines will not meet at the same points.

Comment: *** Picture was wrong!! I fixed it!

Comment: I think you need some more conditions on $A$ and $B$ to ensure that the tangents intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram in [fleablood’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2287046/265466) is the key to this proof. Let $P$ and $Q$, respectively, be the intersections of $\overline{AM}$ and $\overline{BM}$ with circle $O_1$, and $R$, $S$ be the intersections of $\overline{AN}$ and $\overline{BN}$, respectively, with circle $O_2$. We have $AP=AT=AR$, $MP=MQ$, $BQ=BT=BS$ and $NR=NS$. We also have $AM=AP+NP$, $BM=BQ+MQ$, $AN=AR+NR$ and $BN=BS+NS$. The rest should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

http://staff.argyll.epsb.ca/jreed/math20p/circles/images/tangentProof.png[image]

So it's very clear that $MA = MB$ and $NA= NB$.

====

Okay.  $\angle TMA \cong \angle TMB$ because $MA$ and $MB$ are both tangents to the same circle.  So $\triangle TMA \cong \triangle TMB$ by Angle ($\angle TMA = \angle TMB$) Side ($AT=AT$) Angle ($\angle MTA = \angle MTB$).  So $AM = AN$.

Similarly $BN = BM$.

So $AN + BM = AM + BN$.

Comment: I appricate this but this is not what the proof is asking. How can this be used to show AM+BN=AN+BM

Comment: Are you kidding me?  AM = AN and BN = BM so AM + BN = AN + BM.

Comment: Hmm... from the OP’s diagram, it’s pretty clear that $AM\ne AN$. Did something change in the question since you posted this answer?

Comment: @amd yes! The picture was wrong originally! The picture that is up now is correct!